# How to do this in SQL query, find similar rows percentage match based on this condition?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an SQL Table like this:

```
MD5                         BlockHash
randommd51                  randstr1
randommd51                  randstr2
randommd51                  randstr3
randommd52                  randstr2
randommd52                  randstr2
randommd52                  randstr1
randommd52                  randstr7
randommd53                  randstr2
randommd53                  randstr1
randommd53                  randstr2
randommd53                  randstr3
randommd54                  randstr4
randommd54                  randstr55
```

I have another variable in Python called "query" (dictonary). The dictionary key is the MD5 value, and the values are "BlockHash".

Like this:

```
{ "randommd55": ["randomstr1", "randomstr2", "randomstr1"] }
```

My Main Goal:

I want to search similar files. MD5 value represent the full file's MD5 value. It will change, even If there is a 1-bit difference in a file.

For each file, I take random 1KB blocks and hash them.

So now, I have a query dictionary consisting of multiple block hash. I want to compare the query blockhash with files inside SQL table.

I want to see how many blockhash match between the query file & the sql files (MD5 is unqiue for each file).

For example:

File where md5=="randommd51" is, have 2 blockhash in common (randstr1, randstr2). So it is a 2/3 = 66.666% match

File where md5=="randommd52" is, also have 2 blockhash in common (randomstr1, randomstr2). So it is a 2/4, 50% match. Note that randomstr2 repeat two times in this file. But it only repeat 1 time in queryhash. So it is only 2/4 match (50%).

I want to calculate the percentage match for each unique MD5 in SQL, in a fast way. I will have millions of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the proportion of block hashes that match for each MD5:

```
select md5,
       avg( (blockhash in ('randomstr1', 'randomstr2', 'randomstr3') ) as matching_ratio
from t
group by md5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, for each md5 key/blockhash list value in you `query` dictionary, you want to calculate the percentage of matches of blockhash values on the database for that md5 value.

```
def flatten(items):
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

query =  { "randommd55": ["randomstr1", "randomstr2", "randomstr1"] } # plus other key, value entries

for md5, blockhash_list in query.items():
    set1 = set(blockhash_list) # set of blockhash values in query
    # conn is database connection using perhaps pymysql
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select BLOCKHASH from the_table where MD5 = %s', (md5,))
    set2 = set(flatten(cursor.fetchall())) # set of blockhash values on database for this md5
    # do we need to test for an empty set2; we don't want to divide by zero?
    l = len(set2)
    if l == 0:
        print('md5 {} does not exist on the database.'.format(md5))
    else:
        fraction = len(set1 & set2) / l
        print('md5 = {}, percentage = {:.3}'.format(md5, fraction))
```